# pgid in signal handler is different from the real pgid

Tags: c, signals, process-group

I have the following simple program that sets the main program's pgid and pgroup for STDIN. Then, I have a signal handler that prints the pgid of the current process and the pgid of the process from which the signal is sent. Here is my code

```
pid_t pid;

void handler(int signum, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* context){
    printf("pgid is %d, shell_pgid is %d \n", getpgid(siginfo->si_pid), pid);
}


int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;


    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART; 

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    pid = getpid();
    setpgid(pid, pid);
    tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, pid);


      while(1){

      }
}
```

However, when I press ^C, the output I get is

```
^Cpgid is 335, shell_pgid is 3924
```

Aren't they supposed to be the same since the program is running in the main program and the signal is also sent from the same source?

Comment: Is the `setpgid()` call succeeding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused about how process group IDs work.

First, I tidied up your source:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

pid_t pid;

void
handler (int signum, siginfo_t * siginfo, void *context)
{
  printf ("in signal handler pid is %d, getpgid(pid) is %d \n",
          pid, getpgid (pid));
  printf
    ("in signal handler siginfo->si_pid is %d, getpgid(siginfo->si_pid) is %d \n",
     siginfo->si_pid, getpgid (siginfo->si_pid));
  exit (0);
}


int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct sigaction sa;

  memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
  sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;

  sigaction (SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

  pid = getpid ();
  printf ("before call pgid is %d pid=%d\n", getpgid (pid), pid);
  setpgid (pid, pid);
  printf ("after setpgid call pgid is %d pid=%d\n", getpgid (pid), pid);
  tcsetpgrp (STDIN_FILENO, pid);
  printf ("after tcsetprgrp call pgid is %d pid=%d\n", getpgid (pid), pid);

  while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

The main change is that if your handler takes three parameters, you need to use `SA_SIGINFO` and specify the handler in `sa_sigaction` not `sa_handler`. Without that, your handler may be getting invalid second and third arguments.

Next I fixed your handler so it printed out `si_pid` as well as `pid`.

I also put in some additional debugging.

This is what happens when I run straight from the shell:

```
$ ./x
before call pgid is 15136 pid=15136
after setpgid call pgid is 15136 pid=15136
after tcsetprgrp call pgid is 15136 pid=15136
^Cin signal handler pid is 15136, getpgid(pid) is 15136
in signal handler siginfo->si_pid is 0, getpgid(siginfo->si_pid) is 15136
```

Note that `siginfo->si_pid` reports as 0 because `si_pid` is only filled in by signals sent through `kill`. This means 0 is passed to `getpgid()` which returns the `PGID` of the calling process, which is unsurprisingly the same as `getpgid(pid)` returned on the previous line.

Here's what happens if I kill it with `kill -SIGINT` from another process rather than pressing `^C`.

```
$ ./x
before call pgid is 15165 pid=15165
after setpgid call pgid is 15165 pid=15165
after tcsetprgrp call pgid is 15165 pid=15165
in signal handler pid is 15165, getpgid(pid) is 15165
in signal handler siginfo->si_pid is 14858, getpgid(siginfo->si_pid) is 14858
```

As you can see the last line reports the PID of the process sending the `kill`.

In both the above examples, the `PGID` is already equal to the `PID` when the process is started. Why is that? Well, we launched one command from the command line, so there is one process group (only), so the `PGID` is always going to be the `PID`.

So what happens if we launch a process group where we are not the first process? Try this:

```
$ echo | ./x
before call pgid is 15173 pid=15174
after setpgid call pgid is 15174 pid=15174
after tcsetprgrp call pgid is 15174 pid=15174
in signal handler pid is 15174, getpgid(pid) is 15174
in signal handler siginfo->si_pid is 14858, getpgid(siginfo->si_pid) is 14858
```

Note this one I had to kill with `kill -SIGINT` because a `^C` goes to the process group which is (after the `PGID` is changed) only `echo`. So, the `PGID` on entry is `15173` (the PID of `echo`) but gets changed to be `15174` (as you requested).

I think it's all working as expected.

I think the problem you have is in essence in your signal handler. First, you seem to be expecting `si_pid` to be filled in. Secondly, your `printf` says you are printing `pgid` and `shell_pgid` (two `PGID`s, whereas actually you are printing the `PGID` of the process issuing the kill (or if none the result of `getpgid(0)` which is the `PGID` of the calling process), then the PID of process - i.e. both the wrong way round and a `PID` and a `PGID`. And also I suspect setting up the handler wrong may give you a junk second parameter anyway.

Comment: @abligh I ran your program and killed in the main, but my output is 

221:src frabi$ ./getpgid
before call pgid is 4758 pid=4758
after setpgid call pgid is 4758 pid=4758
after tcsetprgrp call pgid is 4758 pid=4758
^Cin signal handler pid is 4758, getpgid(pid) is 4758 
in signal handler siginfo->si_pid is 335, getpgid(siginfo->si_pid) is 335

Comment: Right, so you launched from the shell directly so before you started you `PGID` and your `PID` are already equal. Looks like when you kill it, your are getting an `si_pid` set. That probably depends on how your `^C` processing is done. I was logged in via `ssh`. Whatever, I presume 335 is the PID of your shell.